# What is the net force on an object which is moving with a constant velocity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, velocity

Imagine a toy car moving with a constant velocity. By Newton's second law of motion we can see that $F=ma$ and, since there is no acceleration, the net force is zero. But still we can experience a force on us downwards. Can anyone explain the logical reason behind this?

Comment: I don't see any attempt to research this. It is a typical homework concept question looking at the vector nature of forces.

Answer (score 1):

```
net force is zero
```

Not the force is 0. Force in the downward direction is balanced by normal 
action of floor/road

Answer (score 1):

This might seem a bit counter intuitive, but we actually *don't* really experience the force on us downwards.  When it is only gravity acting to pull you down (i.e. freefall) without any other forces, you cannot feel that gravity is acting on you.  It feels the same as floating without any forces.

What the toy car actually experiences is the *upwards* force from the ground pushing back on it.  So it's somewhat non-intuitive, but you could say in this case the logical reason that you feel the ground pushing you is because you *don't* feel the force of gravity on it's own.  You only feel the *reactions* to the gravitational force.  In this case, the reaction is the normal force from the ground, which prevents the car from accelerating through the ground as it wants to continue doing due to the gravitational acceleration.

This is how you get no net force, but still feel the forces acting against gravity.

Comment: I have a question related to your comment, but not really related to the OP question. 
You say: "When it is only gravity acting to pull you down (i.e. freefall) without any other forces, you cannot feel that gravity is acting on you. It feels the same as floating without any forces. What the toy car actually experiences is the upwards force from the ground pushing back on it."
My question is: What is the reason why, even though we cannot feel the pulling of gravity, we are still "pulled" somehow to the ground?

Comment: @AWanderingMind Usually it's called the equivalence principle https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_principle  Gravity actually seems to act more like a pseudoforce/inertial effect instead of an actual force being applied to the body, in general relativity.  As far as human observation goes, that is also how we experience it.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that force, velocity and acceleration are vector quantities. When you are talking about $\vec{F}, \vec{v}, \vec{a},$ you must also specify the direction of motion.

I am guessing that the direction of motion in your case is independent on the direction on which the gravity act upon.

So there is not net force on the direction of motion because the object is moving with constant velocity. And there is no net force on the up-down direction because the force of gravity is equaled by the normal action of the whatever the car is moving on (which is based on electric repulsion at the fundamental level).

$$F=ma=m\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}$$
if $v=\text{const}$
$$\frac{d}{dt}x=\text{const}$$
which means that:
$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=0$$